# ZSH `--color=auto` doesn't work

Tags: shell, zsh

For some reason when I execute the following:

```
ls --color=auto
```

Results with:

```
ls: illegal option -- -
usage: ls [-ABCFGHLOPRSTUWabcdefghiklmnopqrstuwx1] [file ...]
```

Not sure why this is happening, I'm wondering if anyone else has had the same issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Depending on the OS, `ls` doesn't always have the functionalities.

There are ***two different*** versions of `ls` :

- One from the BSD world (for example Mac OS X version) :

The `--color=auto` doesn't work, use `-G` instead.

- One from the Free Software Foundation (Linux for example) :

You can use the `--color=auto` and the `-G` option does not list group.

By the way, this has nothing to do with zsh, except if you assign custom PATH in your `.zshrc`.

**EDIT :**

If you want the FSF version of `ls`, simply download the latest [coreutils](http://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/coreutils/) ([8.4](http://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/coreutils/coreutils-8.4.tar.gz) now) and compile them.

This will allow you to use the this version.
[image: ls-color]

Comment: Excellent input, I'm using OS X, but I also want to use the same profile in my Ubuntu machine, is that going to far?

Comment: I suppose it really doesn't have much to do with ZSH or OS X for that matter, I just want pretty colored directories and what not.

Comment: Of course you can ! I edited my post to show how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of system are you using? Solaris/BSD ls don't support --color.